# How to use date and time ACF fields to hide the_content() based on whether time has passed

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF fields which hold the closing date and closing time.
I have the following variables:

```
$closing_date = get_field( "closing_date" );
$closing_time = get_field( "closing_time" );

$cdate = $closing_date ." " . $closing_time; 
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
$date2 = new DateTime("$cdate");
```

Now I need to hide content if time has passed.
The code works well outside a function such as:

```
if(new DateTime() > $date2)
{?>
<span class="" style="color:white; background:grey; padding:2px; border-radius:2px;"> 
<?php echo "Closed"; ?></span>
<?php
}
```

But inside the function it won't work despite declaring the global variables

```
add_filter('the_content', 'hide_post_contents');

function hide_post_contents( $content ) {
   global $date2;
   if (new DateTime() > $date2) {
        return '<h3>This content is not available </h3>
        <p>Please feel free to check out other content.</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

However when I add the date manually as below, it works.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'hide_post_contents');

function hide_post_contents( $content ) {
   if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("09-03-2021 15:00")) {
        return '<h3>This content is not available </h3>
        <p>Please feel free to check out other content.</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Content still displays even when time has passed which is wrong. Cannot get it to work despite several attempts.

Comment: What context are your variables in? Are they global to begin with? And did that section of the code already execute, before the filter is run?

Comment: Yes they are global. I used ```global $date2``` to access it from inside the function.

Comment: I did not mean whether you used the `global` keyword inside your function, but what the scope of the variables itself is.

Comment: They are global variables because they are outside the function.

Comment: Variables are not global because they are outside of a _specific_ function, they are only global when they are outside of _any_ function. That’s why I asked about the _context_ to begin with.

Comment: Right. That's the only function I have in that file so I assume that makes them global.

Comment: _What_ file? If this is inside any template partial, then that itself might get included inside a function, and then its not global any more.

Comment: The file is single-tender.php which is a custom file for displaying content for the tender custom post type. So what do you suggest I do?

Comment: And how is the content output in that template file? Calling `get_the_content`, or something similar? Then it might perhaps make more sense to wrap _that_ into your date check in that location, instead of trying to use the filter.

Comment: Sorry sorry just checked. The file is content.php which is called inside single-tender.php like this ```while ( have_posts() )
                    {
                        the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-single/content', get_post_format() );
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() )
                        {
                            comments_template();
                        }
                    }``` so we are now editing the content.php file.

Comment: Just as you suggested, I have used the existing content() function and wrapped it inside the date condition which worked! Thanks.